# After uninstalling an extension in Opencart3, there are remnants in user groups

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I installed an extension into my opencart 3 website but later want to remove it .

I have done the following:

1. i have uninstalled from extension/extension/module
2. gone to modification and removed it then refreshed
3. tracked each of the files and removed them one by one
4. i did the theme refresh from dashboard and did modification refresh

yet i am still seeing this in the user group permission box

how do i remove the un-checked categories from the permission box?

please refer to image link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdsPS.png

Comment: I just tried uninstalling one of my own mods in the same way (uninstall the module, uninstall the associated modification, delete the files from disk and refresh the mod cache) - and my mod disappeared from the list in the permissions box as expected. The list is stored as JSON and it's created by looking at files in the admin 'controller' dir. Have you definitely deleted the appropriate files from the admin 'controller' dir?

Comment: Yes. I confirmed it again and i had removed it earlier

Answer (score 0):

**100% Solved**

you can remove her ocmod xml file

You are going to admin modification page and remove particulars ocmod files as well

i hope this articles very usefull for you. if you are happy with my answer you can keep upvote and review my answer.

You can see screenshot as well :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Felix but like i mentioned i am using Opencart 3 . the image is for opencart 2.

secondly, it wasnt installed using OCMOD.XML file.

This is the installation process:

 it was uploaded directly and then refreshed the modifications
then went to extensions/modules to install it.


presently it isnt showing in the modifications page or extension/module.

so my question is tis:
how do i remove the permission categories from the user group in opencart 3